# I am building an interest calculating app, my project builds fine with 1 warning, but it will not open on my device

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

The warning eclipse gives me is an unsued import warning on the View.OnClickListener, but i am using it... I am pretty confident this is where my error lies. Please take a look at my code and correct all errors. This is my first attempt to write an app from scratch. Thank you for your time!

This is my main but it is called SICalculatorActivity

```
package com.codeherenow.sicalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity {

private Button calcButton;
private SeekBar yearsSeek = null;
private EditText principalAmount;
private EditText interestRate;
private TextView scaleReadout;
private TextView resultText;
float totalAmount;
float iRate;
float pAmount;
float years;
String result;

// public int progressChanged=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
    result=resultText.getText().toString();

    scaleReadout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scaleReadout);
    years=Float.parseFloat(scaleReadout.getText().toString());
    calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calc_button);
    yearsSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    principalAmount= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPrincipalAmount);
    pAmount=Float.parseFloat(principalAmount.getText().toString());
    interestRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIntrestRate);
    iRate = Float.parseFloat(interestRate.getText().toString());

    yearsSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        // int progressChanged = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            yearsSeek.setMax(50);
            scaleReadout.setText(progress + " Years");
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Toast.makeText(SeekBarActivity.this, progressChanged +
            // " Years", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            // .show();
        }

    });
    // onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)

    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick1(View v) {
            calculateinterest();
           finish();

        }



        private String calculateinterest() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             totalAmount=(pAmount*(iRate/100)*years);
            result=(totalAmount+"we did it!!");
             return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

  }

}
```

Here is my  main.xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".SICalculatorActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PrincipalAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:text="Principal Amount ($)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrincipalAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PrincipalAmount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PrincipalAmount"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/InterestRate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPrincipalAmount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPrincipalAmount"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:text="Interest Rate"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editIntrestRate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/InterestRate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/InterestRate"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editIntrestRate"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scaleReadout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editIntrestRate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editIntrestRate"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="0 Years"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="@+string/result"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Calc_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:text="Calculate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and im not sure this helps but here is my manifest file as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.codeherenow.sicalculator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.codeherenow.sicalculator.SICalculatorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for taking time to help poor, ignorant, ol me!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override//missing
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calculateinterest();  // It is returning a String but you are not storing it anywhere. (Just Wondering)
       finish();  // I don't know why are you calling the finish() here. So I'm keeping it
        }
    });
```

Your onClick Listener should look like this

calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override//missing
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        result = calculateinterest();
        finish();
    }
});
```

And change your `calculateinterest()` like below

```
private String calculateinterest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String amount = principalAmount.getText().toString();
         String rate = interestRate.getText().toString();

         if (amount.trim().equlas("") || rate.trim().equals(""))
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the values", Toast.Length_SHORT).show();

         else
         {

             pAmount=Float.parseFloat(amount);
             iRate = Float.parseFloat(rate);



             totalAmount=(pAmount*(iRate/100)*years);
             String output = "( " + totalAmount +" we did it!!) ";
             return output;

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick listener is wrong. Its missing the **@override** annotation.

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick1(View v) {
        calculateinterest();
       finish();

    }
```

It should be like this:

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override//missing
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calculateinterest();
       finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not using the "onClick()" method in onClick Listener of your Button 
So essentially when a click is performed on your button calculateinterest() & finish() are not executed.

Cause when the onClick is performed following method is invoked, which in your case doesn't have an implementation

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Move your code in **onClick1(View)** to the Overriden onClick(View) method so it looks like below

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       calculateinterest();

       finish();

    }

    private String calculateinterest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         totalAmount=(pAmount*(iRate/100)*years);
        result=(totalAmount+"we did it!!");
         return result;
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Button calcButton;
    private SeekBar yearsSeek = null;
    private EditText principalAmount;
    private EditText interestRate;
    private TextView scaleReadout;
    private TextView resultText;
    float totalAmount;
    float iRate;
    float pAmount;
    float years;
    String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        scaleReadout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scaleReadout);
        calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calc_button);
        yearsSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        principalAmount= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPrincipalAmount);
        interestRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIntrestRate);

        yearsSeek.setProgress(1);
        yearsSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                yearsSeek.setMax(50);
                scaleReadout.setText(progress + " Years");
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });

        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateinterest();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private String calculateinterest() {
        boolean isValidate = true;

        if(principalAmount.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
            isValidate = false;
            principalAmount.setError("Value Required");
        }

        if(interestRate.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
            isValidate = false;
            interestRate.setError("Value Required");
        }

        if(isValidate){
            pAmount =Float.parseFloat(principalAmount.getText().toString());
            iRate = Float.parseFloat(interestRate.getText().toString());
            years=Float.parseFloat(scaleReadout.getText().toString());
            totalAmount=(pAmount*(iRate/100)*years);
            result=(totalAmount+"we did it!!");
            return result;
        }else{
            return "";
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone! You were all very very close, but everyone seemed to fail to notice that i did not set years to the progress of the seek bar, so when my answer was 0.0 everytime! Here is the good running code that did exactly as i intended

```
package com.codeherenow.sicalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity {

private Button calcButton;
private SeekBar yearsSeek = null;
private EditText principalAmount;
private EditText interestRate;
private TextView scaleReadout;
private TextView resultText;
float totalAmount;
float iRate;
float pAmount;
float years;
String output;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);


    scaleReadout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scaleReadout);

    calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Calc_button);
    yearsSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    principalAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPrincipalAmount);

    interestRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIntrestRate);


    yearsSeek.setProgress(1);
    yearsSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            yearsSeek.setMax(50);
            scaleReadout.setText(progress + " Years");
            years=progress;
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

    });


    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            calculateinterest();
            resultText.setText(output);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

                    //scaleReadout.setText(progress + " Years");
           // setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);
            //finish();

        }
    });}

  private void calculateinterest() {
    String amount = principalAmount.getText().toString();
    String rate = interestRate.getText().toString();

    if (amount.trim().equals("") || rate.trim().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        }
    else{
        pAmount=Float.parseFloat(amount);
        iRate =Float.parseFloat(rate);

        totalAmount=(pAmount*(iRate/100)*years);
         output= "( "+ totalAmount+" we did it!!) ";


 }

 }}
```